# How to fetch data for a specific time period in BigQuery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

Please, I created my table using hour time partition. Please, I would like would like to fetch data that was stored in my table in the last X minutes, eg last 5 minutes.

I tried using this command
SELECT *
FROM `mydataset.mytable`
FOR SYSTEM_TIME AS OF TIMESTAMP_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 5 MINUTE);

But, it returns a lot more rows than what is expected. I typically store 500 rows every 2 minutes, but this query is returning more than 30000 rows

Comment: If data is only added by `insert into`, then you should add a column to include the date of the row creation. https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/default-values#default_value_expression    Think about partition of your table to not query the whole table every time.

Comment: Please provide the row name of your table, which contains the insert timestamp. `Select * from mydataset.mytable WHERE col_timestampe< TIMESTAMP_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 5 MINUTE)`

Comment: How many rows do you have in the table

Comment: Hi @Francis, Did the above comments help you in resolving the issue?

Comment: Hi @Francis, I have posted the answer as Community wiki. So If my answer addressed your question, please consider upvoting and accepting it. If not, let me know so that the answer can be improved. Accepting an answer will help the community members with their research as well.

Answer (score 1):

As @Samuel mentioned in the comment, below example query can be considered to fetch data for a specific time period in BigQuery.

```
Select * from `dataset.table` 
WHERE col_timestamp < TIMESTAMP_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), 
INTERVAL 5 MINUTE)
```

Posting the answer as community wiki for the benefit of the community that might encounter this use case in the future.

Feel free to edit this answer for additional information.